# Unreachable Cities According to the Isoline API

Tags: here-api

I'm currently using the `isoline api` to create a coverage area around `Seattle,WA` based on time traveled.

```
https://isoline.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?app_id=<APP_ID>&app_code=<APP_CODE>&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&rangetype=time&start=geo!47.6062,-122.3221&range=32400
```

However, I've noticed a few sections of map in Washington state that are never covered, even when the time distance is set to the max of 9 hours.

[image]

All of these places are reachable by car/bike/walking and Ocean Shores takes me less than 3 hours to drive to - and with 9 hours of driving I could easily make it into California or Montana.

So is this a `Here-API` bug/limitation or is there something wrong with the way that I am making the call?

Thank you and any help and all help is always appreciated

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the feedback. We will have a look for root cause and get back to you later.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport another weird thing - you can actually reach Ocean Shores if you use the time `10800`. It looks like it breaks somewhere between 3 and 4 hours. You can never reach Neah Bay though.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport - This is still an issue btw, even in the new v8 endpoint - chunks of coastal Washington State are still "unreachable" while using the isoline API